# Bootstrap inline of check box and text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I want to have the view like above.

But i am getting something like below.

[image]

I was wondering how i can achieve it using bootstrap.

My html code.

```
<div class="controle-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="loginButton">
                                <fmt:message key="authentificate" />
                            </button>
                            <input id="_spring_security_remember_me"
                                name="_spring_security_remember_me" type="checkbox" />
                            <fmt:message key="remember.password.time" />
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do something more like..

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="loginButton">
    <fmt:message key="authentificate" />
  </button>
  <label class="checkbox">
  <input id="_spring_security_remember_me" name="_spring_security_remember_me" type="checkbox" class="form-control">
  <fmt:message key="remember.password.time" />
  </label>
</form>
```

This assumes you're using Bootstrap 2.x

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/73070

Comment: You made an inline form (for a navbar or similar). I think he wants an inline alignment in the last control-group of an horizontal form.

Answer (score 0):

Apart the fact you mispelled `control` in your class, it seems you inserted a screenshot from bootstrap3 but you're using bootstrap2.

Comment: bootstrap-transition.js v2.3.0

Comment: yeah. try fixing `controle-group` in `control-group`